# Iterating over directories containing a string shell script

Tags: shell, npm

I have a set of directories, 10 at the moment that are named `client-1, client-2,..., client-10` and 1 directory that is named `nestjs-wrapper`

I want to iterate over the `client` directories, enter each of them and fire `npm install` and `node index.js` in every one.

I could do it by hand, but the number of clients may increment in the future so I would like to automate this process.

So the flow would be something like this:

- in the parent directory I would like to fire `nvm use` to make sure I have the desired node version
- then cd into each directory, fire `npm install` & `node index.js`
- cd back to parent directory
- repeat this until packages are installed in every client directory
- run `docker-compose up` in a detached terminal
- cd from parent directory into a nestjs-wrapper and start it in watch mode with `npm run start:dev`

This is the start of the attempt, it installs the packages in the `client` directories, now I would somehow need to do the rest of the flow:

```
pattern="/home/dario/my-folder/client"
for _dir in "${pattern}-"[[:digit:]]*; do
[ -d "$_dir" ] || continue;
pushd "$_dir" && npm install;
done
```

I would like to start docker-compose from the parent directory in a detached terminal.
To do this, I just created a new script named `start-docker.sh` in which I only have `docker-compose up`.

And after that open a separate dir in the parent directory (one that is not named `client-`) and run `npm run start:dev` in it.

So it would go something like:

```
pattern="client"
for _dir in "${pattern}-"[[:digit:]]*; do
[ -d "$_dir" ] || continue;
pushd "$_dir" && npm install && node index.js;
popd;
done
gnome-terminal -- ./start-docker.sh;
pushd nestjs_wrapper && npm run start:dev;
```

This does the trick, I switched back to relative pathnames. First I iterate over all the `client` directories and install the packages, then after that I bring up docker-compose and start the wrapper in watch mode.

Comment: Please show your own attempt to solve it. For instance, what keeps you from writing a loop? BTW, what happens if there also exists a directory named `client-4711` or `client-abc`? Should this also undergo an `npm install`?

Comment: @Rooter : _in the root_ : What do you mean by _root_? The parent directory of `client-1`?

Comment: Yeah, parent directory of the `client-` directories.
If new `client` directories will be created, they will always be named `client-` and then an incremented number. And in every one, I would like to do an `npm install` and then `node index.js` on everyone of them. 

I do not know how to even approach this, since I am a noob

Comment: Don't show your code in a comment. Put it into your question.

Comment: @user1934428 Sorry, I'm quite new to this. There it is now, hopefully you get what I mean.

Comment: Always narrowly tailor your file-selection in your loop. Consider `"${pattern}-"[[:digit:]]*` which would limit selection to `client-digits` directory names. If you use global rather than relative pathnames, (e.g. `pattern="/full/path/to/client"`) you can just `cd "$_dir"` without having to worry about backtracking. Otherwise you can use `pushd` and `popd` to change and revert the directory or just save `current="$PWD"` and `cd "$_dir" do your thing and `cd "$current"`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried your suggestion on global pathnames, but I ran into a problem.

Comment: Get rid of the `'*'` BEFORE `*"${pattern}-"[[:digit:]]*`. Your `pattern` fully describes the path and prefix.  You also want to reorder the test as `[ -d "$_dir" ] || continue` before the `cd`, e.g. `[ -d "$_dir" ] || continue; cd "$_dir" && npm install; done`

Comment: You can use `cd -` to go to the previous working directory. If you need a stack of directories, which you can undo one by one, use `pushd DIRNAME` instead of `cd DIRNAME` to change to a new directory, and `popd` instead of `cd -` to go back to your previous directory.

Answer (score 0):

Following the input from the comments, here is the working solution:

```
pattern="client"
for _dir in "${pattern}-"[[:digit:]]*; do
[ -d "$_dir" ] || continue;
pushd "$_dir" && npm install && node index.js;
popd;
done
gnome-terminal -- ./start-docker.sh;
pushd nestjs_wrapper && npm run start:dev;
```